# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined when creating data in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am creating a express.js app and I made a database in mongoose for testing purpose. the database is inside a `function seedDB()` that I export to my app.js file. Creating the seed database has no error but when I add a new "review" inside of that data. it is saying `cannot read property "push" of undefined` even though my mongoose model is set correctly.

I have two collections inside mongoDB called "tours" and "reviews"
I tried looking up the tours inside mongo shell with db.tours.find() and I find my "review" which is an array that is associated with the review collection is set up correctly. But when I looked up db.reviews.find() . It is also there but it has about x4 result that my expected result.

I tried checking if I just forgot a parenthesis, curly brace but I think that's not the problem.
I also tried looking at my models over and over and changing again but there is also no problem

```
const tours = require("./models/tours");
const Review = require('./models/reviews');

let tourData = [{
image: "image.jpg",
place: "Place",
name: "name",
description: "this is a description",
price: 1234,
info: "this is a great tour"},
{
image: "image.jpg",
place: "Place",
name: "name",
description: "this is a description",
price: 1234,
info: "this is a great tour"},
{
image: "image.jpg",
place: "Place",
name: "name",
description: "this is a description",
price: 1234,
info: "this is a great tour"},
]

function seedDB(){
tours.deleteMany({}, (err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("removed tours!");
        //add a few tours
        tourData.forEach(function(seeds){
            tours.create(seeds, (err, data)=> {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log('added all tours!');
                    //create a comment
                    Review.create(
                        {
                        text: "this place is great! ",
                        author: "Arnold"
                        }, (err, comment)=> {
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err)
                        } else {
                            tours.reviews.push(comment); //why is this undefined? I set it up correctly
                            tours.save();
                            console.log("created new review")
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
});
};

module.exports = seedDB
```

up until `console.log('added all tours!');` it is going well but when I put the `Review.create()`, it now has error specifically the `tours.reviews.push(comment);`

```
//tours.js model
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ToursSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
image: String,
place: String,
name: String,
description: String,
price: Number,
info: String,
creator: {
  id: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "User"
  },
  username: String
},
reviews:[
  {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Review"
  }
]
 });


let Tours = mongoose.model('Tour', ToursSchema);

 module.exports = Tours;
```

reviews.js model

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var reviewSchema = mongoose.Schema({ //I also tried doing new Mongoose.Schema({
text: String,
author: String
  });

  module.exports = mongoose.model('Review', reviewSchema);
```

expected results in console should be

```
 removed tours!
 added all tours!
 added all tours!
 added all tours!
 created new review
 created new review
 created new review
```

and the actual results in the mongo database is have an `array of reviews` inside the `tours collections`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple things:

1. `tours` is your model, not your instance. You want to push into the reviews of one or all of your instances, which in your case is `data`. So in your case you can do something like `data[0].reviews.push(comment)`. I can see how you this gut mixed up, since `tours` is lowercase, which makes it look like a instance, not a model.
2. The second worst variable name after `data` is `data2` :-P
3. Consider replacing your callback with the far easier to read and maintain async/await syntax
4. don't directly require your models, but rather register your models and use mongoose.model('tours')

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.From now on, I will try to make a variable that makes the most sense as to not confuse my variables and instances. I have also uppercase the first letter of Tours. also. I will do all what you said here because it is a good practice.